# Is it possible for iOS app distribution through API calls

Tags: ios, api, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

I built an iOS application. I want to test it outside of the organization which is working fine through testflight app testing. I manually configured everything like bundle id, and etc.

I created one web portal to upload the IPA file into my server. I got that IPA file created by one apple developer account. Now, I want to change the bundle ID and provisioning profile in my Apple developer account.

Through API calls, I want to change the IPA file. I would like to create bundle ID, provisioning profile & everything through API calls. Even handling TestFlight external testers, select build versions.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look at [Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane), which should help you automate most of the tasks you're looking for.

> fastlane is a tool for iOS, Mac, and Android developers to automate tedious tasks like generating screenshots, dealing with provisioning profiles, and releasing your application.